# Adding a Png-file to a JButton

Tags: java, swing, png, jbutton, imageicon

```
mainpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(25,25,1,1));
JButton buttons[][] = new JButton[25][25];
ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("wall_down_right_player.png");
for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<25; j++){
        JButton button = new JButton(image);
        buttons[i][j]= button;
        mainpanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
    }   
}
```

I was wondering why this is not working maybe someone can help me :D

Comment: What you want as a result and what is the current one?

Comment: yes ty :DDDD very nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
mainpanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(25,25,1,1));
JButton buttons[][] = new JButton[25][25];
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("wall_down_right_player.png"));
for(int i=0; i<25; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<25; j++){
        JButton button = new JButton();
        button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
        buttons[i][j]= button;
        mainpanel.add(buttons[i][j]);
    }   
}
```

**Update:**

I suggest you create a folder say, **resources** and put your image there. Then, you change the code as follows:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/wall_down_right_player.png"));`
```

Comment: Thank you for ur solution, but I think the problem is that netbeans doesn't find the picture. Although it is in my package ... Maybe u know how to fix that :D

Comment: `"resources/wall_down_right_player.png"` if you put a leading slash, like this `"/resources/wall_down_right_player.png"` then the resource can be found from a a class in any package. the leading `/`denotes to search for the resource from the 'root' of the class path.